# Can some one explain this code

Tags: matlab

I found this page ([How to capture raw IQ data from a RTL-SDR dongle and FM demodulate with MATLAB](http://aaronscher.com/wireless_com_SDR/RTL_SDR_AM_spectrum_demod.html)) and I want someone to explain the code for me in more details if possible.

This is the code:

```
function y = loadFile(filename)
%  y = loadFile(filename)
%
% reads  complex samples from the rtlsdr file
fid = fopen(filename,'rb');
y = fread(fid,'uint8=>double');
y = y-127.5;
y = y(1:2:end) + i*y(2:2:end);
```

Comment: What bit don't you understand about the code? You can type `help fopen` in MATLAB to learn about the `fopen` function (and similar for any other function). If you have difficulty with basic MATLAB syntax, I suggest you read [these tutorials](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html).

Comment: 2 pieces actually first is the: y = fread(fid,'uint8=>double');i just understood that it convert it to double i believe. and second is:y = y(1:2:end) + i*y(2:2:end); it gave me an array so the first term was from the first element to the second until the end, however when it came to the imaginary part i couldn't figure how it was taken non of the numbers made sence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fid = fopen(filename,'rb');
y = fread(fid,'uint8=>double');
```

This function opens a file in read (binary) mode, then read the file like it contains `uint8` data and make it like it was `double` data.

```
y = y-127.5;
```

For every data in the array, decrease the value by 127.5.

```
y = y(1:2:end) + i*y(2:2:end);
```

Now take every two follows numbers in the array, and make them a complex value, for example:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = y(1:2:end) + i*y(2:2:end);
% Result: y = [1 + 2i, 3 + 4i, 5 + 6i]
```